# jpa eclipselink subquery in from clause

Tags: jpa, subquery, eclipselink

I read here 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause

that eclipselink support subquery in from clause

but when i'm using this query

```
queryString2="SELECT NEW dz.com.naftal.erp.domain.view.MouvementProduitView('VAR',t.cds,SUM(t.mntttc)) " +
             "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT m.mouvementProduitViewPK.cds as cds,m.mouvementProduitViewPK.referenceDocument,m.mouvementProduitViewPK.typeDocument " +
             "m.mntttc as mntttc FROM MouvementProduitView m WHERE m.mouvementProduitViewPK.cds IN :cdss " +
             "AND m.mouvementProduitViewPK.typeDocument IN :typeDocuments " +
             "AND m.dateOperation BETWEEN :dateDu AND :dateAu GROUP BY m.mouvementProduitViewPK.cds ORDER BY m.mouvementProduitViewPK.cds) AS t GROUP BY t.cds"
```

I'm getting this error

```
SEVERE [global]
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT NEW.............. 
[388, 388] The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.
[389, 389] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
[426, 447] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

does any buddy knows if the subquery in from clause is actually working, and if No is there any other way to do this unless using native query.

PS: I m using eclipselink 2.5.0.v20130507

Comment: an error that says "SELECT NEW ..." and a query that doesn't have that text? so you aren't presenting the same query

Comment: pasted the wrong query, check the edited one.

Comment: the message is nothing to do with the subquery and everything to do with "select new". So how are you invoking it? you also don't have a candidate entity in the FROM, and the EclipseLink page example does have a candidate.

Comment: I have a constructor in the MouvementProduitView with the 3 parameters, so the select new  work if i use select new .... from MouvementProduitView m it works, also i tried to use a entity condidate with the select subquery and i got the same error

Comment: @NeilStockton, it was the candidate entity, it doesn't work the first time i tried it because i had a syntaxe error ( the GROUP BY clause in the sub query), so you had the right answer

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is simple: Your query is malformed, is missing a comma in the select distinct... you have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.mouvementProduitViewPK.cds as cds,
    m.mouvementProduitViewPK.referenceDocument,
    m.mouvementProduitViewPK.typeDocument //Here is missing the comma
    m.mntttc as mntttc 
FROM MouvementProduitView m
```

Between the third and fourth line is missing the comma, it should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.mouvementProduitViewPK.cds as cds,
    m.mouvementProduitViewPK.referenceDocument,
    m.mouvementProduitViewPK.typeDocument, //put at the end of this line the comma
    m.mntttc as mntttc 
FROM MouvementProduitView m
```

Comment: that was not that, but it still has a syntax error, I forgot to remove the GROUP BY clause from the sub query

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'AS' string after the subquery. The article you presented does not use this construction.

Comment: my bad ^^', I pasted the wrong query, check the edited post.