# JPA Join with aggregate function

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am a beginner when it comes to JPA and I am struggling to write the proper entity classes for my database structure.

Firstly, here are my tables:

```
create table article (
  id varchar(100) not null primary key,
  title varchar(255) not null
)
create table article_provider (
  providerId varchar(60) not null,
  articleId varchar(100) null,
  isOnSale BOOL NOT NULL,
  constraint article_provider_articleid_fk foreign key (articleId) references article (id) on update cascade on delete cascade
)
```

As you can see I have a one-to-many relationship (every article can have 0..n providers).
Now when accessing articles I would also like to know, if the article is on sale by any of it's providers. For this I would use the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT article.*, MAX(article_provider.isOnSale) AS isOnSale FROM article
LEFT JOIN article_provider ON article.id = article_provider.articleId
GROUP BY article.id
```

How would I best go about fetching this type of result using Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: article_provider looks like a join table and it looks more like many to many relationship

Comment: How is this many to many if `article_provider` has a singular `articleId` reference? Every `article_provider` has _one_ `article`, every `article` can have any number of `article_provider` entries. Note that `article_provider` does not denote information about the provider, it denotes information about how that provider offers that article (i.e. price, whether it's on sale, etc.). `provider` is a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not right -- you use attributes in SELECT clause that are not in GROUP BY clause, but for example to select Article.id + MAX(whatever) you can use something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Article> query = builder.createQuery(Article.class);
Root<Article> root = query.from(Article.class);
Join<Article, ArticleProvider> join = root.join(Article_.provider, JoinType.LEFT);
query.multiselect(root.get(Article_.id), builder.max(sale));
query.groupBy(root.get(Article_.id));
// query will return collection of scalar attributes (ID + Number)
Object result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList()
```

To select exactly Article.* + MAX(sales) you would need to use the above as a <strike>subquery</strike> and join again with Article entity.

But there are simillar of examples elsewhere: [How do I write a MAX query with a where clause in JPA 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348354/how-do-i-write-a-max-query-with-a-where-clause-in-jpa-2-0)

EDIT:

- another tip: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/
- correction/clarification: I have only assumed you want to use Criteria API where subquery and combining the results for Hibernate is probably the only way.  But you may try to use JPA query language and/or different provider where subquery with multiple results can be used -- [jpa eclipselink subquery in from clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530464/jpa-eclipselink-subquery-in-from-clause)

Comment: If I group by the primary key in `article` there can only be one result for every column in the `article` table, right? So, how is `article.*` not ok then?
And I don't need only the article ID, I need everything in the article table.

Comment: @diesieben07 see for example http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/04/group-by-non-aggregate-columns/

Comment: I am aware of the problems described in that article, but they cannot occur when grouping by the primary key, can they?

Comment: you cannot reference columns in select clause that are missing in group by clause -- what is exactly what you are doing by 'article.*'

Comment: Well, I tried the query right before I posted here and it worked fine.

Comment: out of curiosity -- what database are you using? in oracle similar query ends with ORA-00979 (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm)
if you group by id, you can have several lines for such an id (i understand, they are probably the same in case of primary key) -- but how the database knows, what row to show you, if they are multiple without specifying another aggregate function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164865/discussion-between-bubak-and-diesieben07).

Comment: I have done some more research, and my query is actually completely fine according to newer SQL standards (SQL-99 and onwards). See these articles: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html

Comment: I have answered in discussion above.